# Count the number of duplicate values in row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to set number if this value is previously present in row. I want below output.

```
Date                        Empno           Count
-------------------------------------------------------
2018-08-01 06:00:00.000     10103612    1
2018-08-02 14:30:54.000     10103610    1
2018-08-03 06:30:00.000     10103660    1
2018-08-04 06:00:00.000     10103660    2
2018-08-04 19:15:00.000     10103610    2
2018-08-05 12:00:00.000     10103603    1
2018-08-05 17:30:00.000     10103603    2
2018-08-06 06:30:00.000     10103660    3
2018-08-06 07:00:00.000     10103531    1
```

ie, If `Empno` comes for the second or third time in list, I want to show its count in the very next column. You can see that in `10103660`, it occur in the list 3 times, so the count increments for each time in list.

Answer (score 2):

[ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) combined with [OVER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will give you a count of how many rows have the same value in the `Empno` column.

The following will return `EmpnoCount` which will tell you how many records have the same value in the `Empno` column as the record with the `EmpnoCount`:

```
SELECT [Date],
       [Empno],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Empno] ORDER BY [Date]) AS EmpnoCount
FROM INSERT_TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY [EmpnoCount] DESC
```

The results should be in descending order of the most duplicated `Empno` value.

**UPDATE #1**

[Working example link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cae97/1) to SQL Fiddle that shows the results of the above query.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do a `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `OVER()` window function

```
SELECT [Date], 
       [Empno], 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Empno] ORDER BY [Date]) as [Count]
FROM   yourtable
ORDER BY [Date];
```

Comment: @PravinK what version of SQL Server are you using ?